# Converting a Function to Use a Passed in Variable in Angular 2 App Using Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am using observables to pull in data in my Angular 2 app. Right now I have several services/components doing pretty much the same thing, so I'd like to make this "DRYer" by refactoring so I can just pass in the one parameter that's different in the API call I'm making in the components. That way I can use one service for each of the components needing this.

Let me first show what IS working (for comparison's sake):

In my service I had this:

```
getByCategory() {
    this._url = "https://api.someurl.com/v0/contacts/group/staff?limit=15&apikey=somekey";
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsHandler);
}
_errorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And in my component I was subscribing to this like this:

```
this.contactService.getByCategory()
     .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
      responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

Again, all of the above code IS working.

But because the only thing that's different between the calls from various components is one parameter (group) in the API call, I'd like to refactor to make it something like this:

```
getByCategory(group) {
    const q = encodeURIComponent(group);
    this._url = "https://api.someurl.com/v0/contacts/group/${q}?limit=15&apikey=somekey";
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsHandler);
}
_errorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And then in the components I would subscribe to this, while also passing in the one group parameter that's different for each component, like this:

```
   this.contactService.getByStage('staff')
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

When I try this, I don't get any errors, but I also don't get any data printed to the view. Is there something I'm missing here in the conversion of this function?

Comment: that should work.  what happens if you log the this._url?

Comment: I get this:
"https://api.someurl.com/v0/contacts/group/${q}?limit=15&apikey=somekey"

Comment: looks like maybe ${q} isn't getting interpolated correctly?  I feel like you would want that to be 'staff' in your example.

Comment: Interestingly, in another component and service I'm using something very similar - with the same kind of interpolation - and it's working perfectly. Not sure why it's not interpolating in this case. Here I am passing a string value, whereas in the other one (that IS working) I am passing in a contact.id.

Comment: Ah!!! I got it. It needs backticks, not quotes. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the url needs to use backticks instead of quotes, because of the interpolation being used in the url passed to the API.

```
this._url = `https://api.someurl.com/v0/contacts/group/${q}?limit=15&apikey=somekey`;
```